# Bulk edit tables and columns descriptions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

In a question on StackOverflow I found this query, that displays table and column description for all the tables in current database:

```
SELECT      u.name + '.' + t.name AS [table],
            td.value AS [table_desc],
            c.name AS [column],
            cd.value AS [column_desc]
FROM        sysobjects t
INNER JOIN  sysusers u
    ON      u.uid = t.uid
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties td
    ON      td.major_id = t.id
    AND     td.minor_id = 0
    AND     td.name = 'MS_Description'
INNER JOIN  syscolumns c
    ON      c.id = t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties cd
    ON      cd.major_id = c.id
    AND     cd.minor_id = c.colid
    AND     cd.name = 'MS_Description'
WHERE t.type = 'u'
ORDER BY    t.name, c.colorder
```

This helps me a lot because I immediately see all the tables and columns that have no description.
Now, it would be really cool to be able to directly edit these descriptions.
Is there a software that allows bulk editing of descriptions for tables and/or columns?

Comment: Bulk editing how? If there is something you can programmatically do to add a description to every column of every table without having to think about it, what value could the description possibly have? (To be honest, documentation around your schema belongs in a data dictionary / source control, not extended properties.)

Comment: Not programmatically. I am only looking for a convenient way to enter the information, like a grid where I can immediately see the blanks and manually fill them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add them in mass but you can generate the commands to do so pretty easily.  I've added two extra columns to the query that have the `sys.sp_addextendedproperty` commands added if there isn't already a description.  You would still have to manually modify the description value for each but this should save you some time.

```
SELECT      u.name + '.' + t.name AS [table],
            td.value AS [table_desc],
            CASE WHEN td.value IS NULL THEN 
                    'EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N''TableDescription'', ' + 
                        '@value=N''This is the table description'' , ' + 
                        '@level0type=N''SCHEMA'',@level0name=N'''+QUOTENAME(u.name)+''', ' + 
                        '@level1type=N''TABLE'',@level1name=N'''+QUOTENAME(t.name)+'''' END AS CreateTableNotes,
            c.name AS [column],
            cd.value AS [column_desc],
            CASE WHEN cd.value IS NULL THEN 
                    'EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N''ColumnDescription'', ' +
                        '@value=N''This is the column description'' , ' +
                        '@level0type=N''SCHEMA'',@level0name=N'''+QUOTENAME(u.name)+''', ' + 
                        '@level1type=N''TABLE'',@level1name=N'''+QUOTENAME(t.name)+''', ' +
                        '@level2type=N''COLUMN'',@level2name=N'''+QUOTENAME(c.name)+'''' END AS CreateColumnNotes
FROM        sysobjects t
INNER JOIN  sysusers u
    ON      u.uid = t.uid
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties td
    ON      td.major_id = t.id
    AND     td.minor_id = 0
    AND     td.name = 'MS_Description'
INNER JOIN  syscolumns c
    ON      c.id = t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties cd
    ON      cd.major_id = c.id
    AND     cd.minor_id = c.colid
    AND     cd.name = 'MS_Description'
WHERE t.type = 'u'
ORDER BY    t.name, c.colorder
```

Comment: Why do you use TableDescription instead of MS_Description?

Comment: Just a typo.  I didn't notice the MS_Description in the JOIN.  It's just a descriptor field so I didn't worry about it when creating the command.